# Failed deploy fabric-couch on openshift platform

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to deploy hyperledger/fabric-couchdb: x86_64-1.0.1 on Openshift platform.
Details of my environment :
openshift v3.4.1.44
kubernetes v1.4.0+776c994

I have deployed fabric-couchDB using following yaml script.
I am running yaml with admin user.This user has restricted access in openshift.

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
#creating Shared PVC
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
        labels:
            io.kompose.service: shared-pvc
        name: shared-pvc
    spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
        resources:
            requests:
                storage: 100Mi

#creating ImageStream couchdb      
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: ImageStream
    metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        name: couchdb
    spec:
        tags:
        - annotations: null
          from:
            kind: DockerImage
            name: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-1.0.1
          generation: null
          importPolicy: {}
          name: x86_64-1.0.1
    status:
        dockerImageRepository: "" 

#Creating couchdb POD
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
        name: couchdb
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: DB_URL
          value: http://localhost:5984/member_db
        - name: COUCHDB_USER
          value: admin
        - name: COUCHDB_PASSWORD
          value: password           
        - name: CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL
          value: DEBUG
        image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-1.0.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: couchdb
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5984
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/couchdb/etc/local.d
          name: couchdb-claim0
        - mountPath: /opt/couchdb/data
          name: couchdb-claim1
        restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: couchdb-claim0
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: shared-pvc         
      - name: couchdb-claim1
        emptyDir: {}   
    test: false
    triggers:
    - type: ConfigChange
    - imageChangeParams:
        automatic: true
        containerNames:
        - couchdb
        from:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: couchdb:x86_64-1.0.1
      type: ImageChange 

kind: List
metadata: {}
```

With this script POD get created and run successfully. 
Below terminal log generated.

```
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.030925Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_log started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.035923Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application folsom started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.074775Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_stats started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.074892Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application khash started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.084266Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_event started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.090430Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application ibrowse started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.096120Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application ioq started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.096256Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application mochiweb started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.096382Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application oauth started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.105579Z nonode@nohost <0.198.0> -------- Apache CouchDB 2.0.0 is starting.
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.105638Z nonode@nohost <0.199.0> -------- Starting couch_sup
[notice] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.140601Z nonode@nohost <0.82.0> -------- config: [admins] admin set to -pbkdf2-ea9beb38474607c1ffb9304d288ba2ff93e2f38a,3ecf788116d8c27020f5012f72114bed,10 for reason nil
[notice] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.173160Z nonode@nohost <0.82.0> -------- config: [couchdb] uuid set to 5b92249aebb2e742f2a86b0cfaeca017 for reason nil
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.219024Z nonode@nohost <0.204.0> -------- open_result error {not_found,no_db_file} for _users
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.284558Z nonode@nohost <0.198.0> -------- Apache CouchDB has started. Time to relax.
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.284667Z nonode@nohost <0.198.0> -------- Apache CouchDB has started on http://127.0.0.1:5986/
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.284794Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.284944Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application ets_lru started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.293670Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application rexi started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.304787Z nonode@nohost <0.204.0> -------- open_result error {not_found,no_db_file} for _nodes
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.326838Z nonode@nohost <0.204.0> -------- open_result error {not_found,no_db_file} for _dbs
[error] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.327172Z nonode@nohost emulator -------- Error in process <0.287.0> with exit value:
{{badmatch,file_exists},[{mem3_shards,fold,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,156}]},{mem3_sync,initial_sync,1,[{file,"src/mem3_sync.erl"},{line,241}]}]}
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.332055Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application mem3 started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.332224Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application fabric started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.345163Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application chttpd started on node nonode@nohost
[notice] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.352322Z nonode@nohost <0.325.0> -------- chttpd_auth_cache changes listener died database_does_not_exist at mem3_shards:load_shards_from_db/6(line:327) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/1(line:315) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/2(line:331) <= mem3_shards:for_docid/3(line:87) <= fabric_doc_open:go/3(line:38) <= chttpd_auth_cache:ensure_auth_ddoc_exists/2(line:187) <= chttpd_auth_cache:listen_for_changes/1(line:134)
[error] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.352374Z nonode@nohost emulator -------- Error in process <0.326.0> with exit value:
{database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,327}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,315}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,331}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,87}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,38}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,187}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,134}]}]}
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.355973Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_index started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.356033Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_mrview started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.356059Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_plugins started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.364246Z nonode@nohost <0.204.0> -------- open_result error {not_found,no_db_file} for _replicator
[notice] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.369132Z nonode@nohost <0.344.0> -------- creating replicator ddoc
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.383827Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_replicator started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.383960Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_peruser started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.401242Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application ddoc_cache started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.417532Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application global_changes started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.417678Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application jiffy started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.429375Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application mango started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.434651Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application setup started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2017-08-23T06:24:51.434778Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application snappy started on node nonode@nohost
[notice] 2017-08-23T06:24:56.352930Z nonode@nohost <0.325.0> -------- chttpd_auth_cache changes listener died database_does_not_exist at mem3_shards:load_shards_from_db/6(line:327) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/1(line:315) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/2(line:331) <= mem3_shards:for_docid/3(line:87) <= fabric_doc_open:go/3(line:38) <= chttpd_auth_cache:ensure_auth_ddoc_exists/2(line:187) <= chttpd_auth_cache:listen_for_changes/1(line:134)
[error] 2017-08-23T06:24:56.353035Z nonode@nohost emulator -------- Error in process <0.452.0> with exit value:
{database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,327}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,315}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,331}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,87}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,38}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,187}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,134}]}]}
[notice] 2017-08-23T06:25:01.354009Z nonode@nohost <0.325.0> -------- chttpd_auth_cache changes listener died database_does_not_exist at mem3_shards:load_shards_from_db/6(line:327) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/1(line:315) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/2(line:331) <= mem3_shards:for_docid/3(line:87) <= fabric_doc_open:go/3(line:38) <= chttpd_auth_cache:ensure_auth_ddoc_exists/2(line:187) <= chttpd_auth_cache:listen_for_changes/1(line:134)
[error] 2017-08-23T06:25:01.354101Z nonode@nohost emulator -------- Error in process <0.549.0> with exit value:
{database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,327}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,315}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,331}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,87}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,38}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,187}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,134}]}]}
[notice] 2017-08-23T06:25:06.354952Z nonode@nohost <0.325.0> -------- chttpd_auth_cache changes listener died database_does_not_exist at mem3_shards:load_shards_from_db/6(line:327) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/1(line:315) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/2(line:331) <= mem3_shards:for_docid/3(line:87) <= fabric_doc_open:go/3(line:38) <= chttpd_auth_cache:ensure_auth_ddoc_exists/2(line:187) <= chttpd_auth_cache:listen_for_changes/1(line:134)
[error] 2017-08-23T06:25:06.355051Z nonode@nohost emulator -------- Error in process <0.614.0> with exit value:
{database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,327}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,315}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,331}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,87}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,38}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,187}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,134}]}]}
[notice] 2017-08-23T06:25:11.355838Z nonode@nohost <0.325.0> -------- chttpd_auth_cache changes listener died database_does_not_exist at mem3_shards:load_shards_from_db/6(line:327) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/1(line:315) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/2(line:331) <= mem3_shards:for_docid/3(line:87) <= fabric_doc_open:go/3(line:38) <= chttpd_auth_cache:ensure_auth_ddoc_exists/2(line:187) <= chttpd_auth_cache:listen_for_changes/1(line:134)
[error] 2017-08-23T06:25:11.355906Z nonode@nohost emulator -------- Error in process <0.711.0> with exit value:
{database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,327}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,315}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,331}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,87}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,38}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,187}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,134}]}]}
[notice] 2017-08-23T06:25:16.356958Z nonode@nohost <0.325.0> -------- chttpd_auth_cache changes listener died database_does_not_exist at mem3_shards:load_shards_from_db/6(line:327) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/1(line:315) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/2(line:331) <= mem3_shards:for_docid/3(line:87) <= fabric_doc_open:go/3(line:38) <= chttpd_auth_cache:ensure_auth_ddoc_exists/2(line:187) <= chttpd_auth_cache:listen_for_changes/1(line:134)
[error] 2017-08-23T06:25:16.357344Z nonode@nohost emulator -------- Error in process <0.776.0> with exit value:
{database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,327}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,315}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,331}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,87}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,38}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,187}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,134}]}]}
[notice] 2017-08-23T06:25:21.357853Z nonode@nohost <0.325.0> -------- chttpd_auth_cache changes listener died database_does_not_exist at mem3_shards:load_shards_from_db/6(line:327) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/1(line:315) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/2(line:331) <= mem3_shards:for_docid/3(line:87) <= fabric_doc_open:go/3(line:38) <= chttpd_auth_cache:ensure_auth_ddoc_exists/2(line:187) <= chttpd_auth_cache:listen_for_changes/1(line:134)
[error] 2017-08-23T06:25:21.358180Z nonode@nohost emulator -------- Error in process <0.873.0> with exit value:
{database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,327}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,315}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,331}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,87}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,38}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,187}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,134}]}]}
[notice] 2017-08-23T06:25:26.358993Z nonode@nohost <0.325.0> -------- chttpd_auth_cache changes listener died database_does_not_exist at mem3_shards:load_shards_from_db/6(line:327) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/1(line:315) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/2(line:331) <= mem3_shards:for_docid/3(line:87) <= fabric_doc_open:go/3(line:38) <= chttpd_auth_cache:ensure_auth_ddoc_exists/2(line:187) <= chttpd_auth_cache:listen_for_changes/1(line:134)
[error] 2017-08-23T06:25:26.359290Z nonode@nohost emulator -------- Error in process <0.938.0> with exit value:
{database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,327}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,315}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,331}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,87}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,38}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,187}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,134}]}]}
[notice] 2017-08-23T06:25:31.359967Z nonode@nohost <0.325.0> -------- chttpd_auth_cache changes listener died database_does_not_exist at mem3_shards:load_shards_from_db/6(line:327) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/1(line:315) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/2(line:331) <= mem3_shards:for_docid/3(line:87) <= fabric_doc_open:go/3(line:38) <= chttpd_auth_cache:ensure_auth_ddoc_exists/2(line:187) <= chttpd_auth_cache:listen_for_changes/1(line:134)
[error] 2017-08-23T06:25:31.360380Z nonode@nohost emulator -------- Error in process <0.1019.0> with exit value:
{database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,327}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,315}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,331}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,87}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,38}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,187}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,134}]}]}
[notice] 2017-08-23T06:25:36.360980Z nonode@nohost <0.325.0> -------- chttpd_auth_cache changes listener died database_does_not_exist at mem3_shards:load_shards_from_db/6(line:327) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/1(line:315) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/2(line:331) <= mem3_shards:for_docid/3(line:87) <= fabric_doc_open:go/3(line:38) <= chttpd_auth_cache:ensure_auth_ddoc_exists/2(line:187) <= chttpd_auth_cache:listen_for_changes/1(line:134)
[error] 2017-08-23T06:25:36.361417Z nonode@nohost emulator -------- Error in process <0.1100.0> with exit value:
{database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,327}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,315}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,331}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,87}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,38}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,187}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,134}]}]}
```

Below are my observations :
1. CouchDB create node with nonode@nohost
2. CouchDB default database _nodes , _dbs, _replicator not created.

Do I need any specific configuration / permission.
I tried to analyze couchDB source but no success :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fabric-couchDB image creates couchDB containers that are supposed to work as stateDB holder for a Hyperledger Fabric peer, and so each couch container is supposed to be connected on a one-to-one basis with a peer. You can look at the docker-compose examples [here in the official doc.](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html?highlight=couchdb#using-couchdb)

That being said, the errors here look normal as there are some initial setup needed in couch to create a few default databases.(Fabric peers do that as a part of the statedb establishment routine) Please see te official [couch config setup doc here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/config/index.html).